How to clear fields on Calendar (Excel)?
How to clear all fields when changing the Month? The month is in dropdown. Like on the image. When I change the month of November to December, the "Ericka Sales" text must be gone.


How is "Erica Sales" entered? Manually, or with a formula or macro? If the former, then you'll probably need a macro with a worksheet change event

it's manually inputted. Can you give me a sample? I'm not that good in macro

Guaranteed this isn't exactly what you're after, but it does  what you asked:  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range): If Target.Address = "$C$1" Then Range("G9").ClearContents: End Sub - each : denotes a new line in the code.

It looks like you are using a custom-made calendar in Excel.
This requires some custom-written macro code.
I presume as the file is premade by someone else it already has that.
My guess is that when you open the file there is a warning to allow macros you got to enable that.
Do be careful that the file is from a trusted person before you enable that.

